# Find a row based on a cell value, copy only part of the row in to a new sheet and the rest of the row into the next row of the new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that has 5 transaction codes ("`IPL`","`ISL`","`IMO`","`IIC`","`CAPO`"). 
I need my macro to find the first 4 transaction codes in column dc of worksheets("sort area"), if it locates it, then take the contents of DE-FN and copy values to a new sheet.
for the last transaction code, i need the macro to find the transaction code in dc, and if it's there take the contents of the row but only the subsequent 8 columns (DE-DL) copy paste values in to worksheet("flat file") and then take the next 8 columns (DM-DS) from the original sheet ("sort area") and copy values in worksheet("flat file") but the following row

for the first part of the macro, i have it separated in to two parts, where i am copying the contents of the entire row, pasting values in to a new sheet, and then sorting the contents and deleting unneeded columns in the new sheet.
I'm struggling because my code is skipping some rows that contain IPL and i don't know why.

i have no idea how to do the last part, CAPO.

Part A (this takes the IPL transaction code and moves it to the new sheet ("flat file"):

```
Sub IPLFlat()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xRRg1 As Range
    Dim xRRg2 As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    Dim xC1 As Long
    Dim xFNum As Long
    Dim xDShName As String
    Dim xRShName As String

    xDShName = "sort area"
    xRShName = "flat file"
    I = Worksheets(xDShName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets(xRShName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    xC1 = Worksheets(xDShName).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    If J = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(xRShName).UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If

    Set xRg = Worksheets(xDShName).Range("DC2:DC" & I)

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "IPL" Then
    Set xRRg1 = xRg(K).EntireRow
    Set xRRg2 = Worksheets(xRShName).Range("A" & J + 1).EntireRow

    xRRg2.Value = xRRg1.Value

    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "IPL" Then
    K = K + 1
    End If
    J = J + 1
    End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Sort Flatfile tab
    Worksheets("flat file").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
         .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("DF1"), Order:=xlAscending
              .SetRange Range("A1", Range("FG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         .Header = xlNo
         .Apply
    End With
    Columns("A:DD").EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: Welcome! It would be better to add an example of the data before and after in both current and desired format. I'm also confused if you are asking 1 or 2 questions, it looks like 2, one about IPL and one CAPO. It is better to ask 2 simple questions than combining.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
Sub stackOverflow()
    Dim sortSheet As Worksheet, flatSheet As Worksheet, newSheet As Worksheet
    Set sortSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sort area")
    Set flatSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("flat file")
    Dim rCount As Long, fCount As Long
    rCount = sortSheet.Cells(sortSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To rCount
        Select Case sortSheet.Cells(i, 107).Value
        Case "IPL", "ISL", "IMO", "IIC"
            Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
            sortSheet.Range(sortSheet.Cells(i, 109), sortSheet.Cells(i, 170)).Copy 'de->109 fn->170
            newSheet.Paste
        Case "CAPO"
            With flatSheet
                fCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                sortSheet.Range(sortSheet.Cells(i, 109), sortSheet.Cells(i, 116)).Copy 'de->109 dl->116
                .Range(.Cells((fCount + 1), 1), .Cells((fCount + 1), 8).PasteSpecial Paste:xlPasteValues 
                sortSheet.Range(sortSheet.Cells(i, 117), sortSheet.Cells(i, 123)).Copy 'dm->117 ds->123
                .Range(.Cells((fCount + 2), 1), .Cells((fCount + 2), 6).PasteSpecial Paste:xlPasteValues 
            End With
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly and that this helps,
Cheers

Comment: not exactly. As there are formulas in my "sort area" worksheet, the cells that are copied over need to pasted as value. Furthermore, i'm looking for the cells to be copied in to a new worksheet in a new workbook and then once the process is done the new workbook to be closed and saved in a specified location: = "G:\CMG\DCM\Operations\Monthly Cycle\Monthly Transaction Upload\" & Range("PB") & "\" & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "yyyy") & "\Flat Files\" & "Citi-INV " & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "mmddyy") & ".csv"

Comment: also the CAPO piece of your code, doesn't work properly. When the code finds the next "CAPO" transaction and goes to copy it over to the new sheet, it copies over the 3rd row (the second part of the original row it first found). Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I have made some edits to hopefully address the issue with pasting only values of the formulas and the overwriting of the row you mentioned. Honestly, I cannot see why the previous version would overwrite any rows, but hopefully you won't see the issue in this version. I do not know your full setup so my solution may not fully answer to your needs, however you should aim to understand the logic behind the code and adapt it to your case. Good luck.